# page.php showing loop of posts and not page content

Tags: posts, theme-development, loop, pages

My front page displays the latest posts using `index.php`.

My `page.php` contains the `wp_header` up top, the `wp_footer` below, and this in between:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
endwhile;
```

My `content-page.php` is supposed to print out `the_content()` and the `the_title()` of the page, but it returns the content and title of all the posts. What am I missing?

The page is set to 'Default Template'.

I've added my page.php and content-page.php below:

page.php:

```
<?php /* Page */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post();
                      get_template_part( 'content', 'page' );
                  endwhile; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

content-page.php

```
<?php /* The template used for displaying page content in page.php */ ?>
<?php
  echo '<div class="row">';
    echo '<div class="col-sm-12">';
      echo the_title( '<h2>', '</h2>');
      echo '<p>' . the_content() . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php /* Main file */ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="container">
    <?php
      if(have_posts()) :
        while (have_posts()) : the_post();
          echo '<div class="row';
          if($count > 2){
            echo ' hideme';
          }
          echo '">';
            echo '<div id="section-'. $count++ .'" class="col-sm-12" style="text-align:center;">';
              echo '<p><a href="' . get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">';
              echo the_post_thumbnail();
              echo '<br>' . get_the_title() . ' // ' . get_the_category_list(', ') . '</a></p>';
            echo '</div>';
          echo '</div>';
        endwhile;
      endif;
    ?>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: With so little information it is hard to even hazard a guess. We'd really need to see the rest of the page.php template but this sounds like someone is using query_posts somewhere or the wrong template is being used to display the page in question.

Comment: If you can echo the query ( global $wp_query; echo '<pre>' . print_r( $wp_query, true ) . '</pre>'; and post that up in the main section, someone might be able to point out at least what the problem is. Also, you might edit your post to include the full page rather than putting it in comments =)

Comment: @Sultenhest Pease add all your code in your question via an [edit]. Do not add code in comments, it is hard to read and most people ignore comments. So add your code where it is supposed to be *inside** your question :-)

Comment: @Privateer + Pieter, I did so now :) Here's a link where you can check out the query [http://sultenhest.dk/zip/ ]

Comment: Can you confirm is it `page.php` and `content-page.php` and not `Page.php` and `Content-page.php`? Capital letters and lower case letters are not the same. Also have you used `query_posts` anywhere in your code?

Comment: @TomJNowell It is all written in lower case. I have not used [query_posts]

Comment: Use back ticks rather than square braces to signify code, it won't turn it into a wiki link either, this isn't mediawiki, it's stack exchange. Also, try using the `body_class` function in your body tag, some of those classes are useful for debugging, eitherway what we're looking at doesn't look like a page, but a post archive of some sort. Have you set this page as the posts page in the reading settings?

Comment: @TomJNowell Ill try body_class. No, under Settings > Reading i chose 'Your latest posts' as what the frontpage is supposed to display

Answer (score 1):

From your query (noted in the comments above), the page you are looking at believes that it is your home page (e.g. your blog).

Notice in the wp_query object the following

```
[found_posts] => 8
[is_home] => 1
```

is_home signifies that it believes that it is showing the home page.

If your files are set up as you say, you should **check your admin panel under Settings > Reading and make sure that the page you are viewing is not set up as your "Posts Page" under the Front Page Displays section**.

If that is not the case then noting what your index.php and/or home.php files contain might be helpful ... as the page you are viewing definitely believes itself to be your home / blog page.

Comment: Okay. I've added my index.php to my question now. Would leaving index.php empty and copying that code to a new template called 'content-home.php' (or something like that), maybe help solve the problem?

Comment: Did you check your reading settings? If not, check them before anything else.

Comment: Yeah, it's set to 'Frontpage Displays: Your latest posts'.